# Aspose pdf java PdfFileSignature setAuthority not working

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, aspose

I'm trying to use Aspose pdf java to digitally sign a document. This is my code

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream signDocument(Document doc, String signedBy) throws Exception {

        PdfFileSignature pdfSignSingle = new PdfFileSignature();
        pdfSignSingle.bindPdf(doc);
        pdfSignSingle.setCertificate(prop.getSigningKeyStorePath(), prop.getKeystorePassword());
        PKCS7 signature = new PKCS7(prop.getSigningKeyStorePath(), prop.getKeystorePassword());
        pdfSignSingle.setSignatureAppearance(prop.getSimploudLogo());

        signature.setAuthority("Authority");
        signature.setDate(new Date());
        signature.setContactInfo("email");
        signature.setLocation("Location");
        signature.setReason("reason");
        pdfSignSingle.sign(1, true, new java.awt.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), signature);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        pdfSignSingle.save(baos);
        pdfSignSingle.dispose();
        doc.dispose();
        return baos;
    }
```

In [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVgCb.png) is shown how the signature looks in adobeReader.

[image: picture]

As you can see both image and Authority are not shown. I tried image to be both in pdf and png format. I've also tried to make it smaller then Rectangle area. As for authority i really need it to be customizable so that text in first line in picture can be
Signed by "customParameter"

Comment: We believe that we have responded to your similar inquiry in Aspose.PDF official support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/t/aspose-pdf-java-pdffilesignature-setauthority-not-working/219738/3). We request you to follow up there so that we can assist you accordingly. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API offers another Class i.e. `SignatureCustomAppearance` which can further be used to set such properties for a signature such as DateSigned, Reason, Location, etc. Please check the following complete code snippet which can fulfill your requirements:

```
String inputFile = "doc.pdf";
String outSignedFile = "out_20.9.pdf";
// Create PdfFileSignature instance
com.aspose.pdf.facades.PdfFileSignature pdfSignSingle = new com.aspose.pdf.facades.PdfFileSignature();
// Bind the source PDF by reading contents of Stream
pdfSignSingle.bindPdf(inputFile);

PKCS7 pkcs = new PKCS7("mykey2.pfx", "pass");
pkcs.setAuthority("Authority");
pkcs.setDate(new Date());
pkcs.setContactInfo("email");
pkcs.setLocation("Location");
pkcs.setReason("reason");
pkcs.setImage(new FileInputStream("simpleLogo.png"));

SignatureCustomAppearance sca = new SignatureCustomAppearance();
sca.setDateSignedAtLabel(null);
sca.setDigitalSignedLabel(null);
sca.setShowReason(true);
sca.setShowLocation(true);
sca.setShowContactInfo(true);

pkcs.setCustomAppearance(sca);

pdfSignSingle.sign(1, true, new java.awt.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), pkcs);
// Set image for signature appearance
//pdfSignSingle.setSignatureAppearance("simpleLogo.png");
// Save final output
pdfSignSingle.save(outSignedFile);
```

As mentioned in the comment below the question, the same inquiry was posted in Aspose.PDF official forum as well at "[Aspose pdf java PdfFileSignature setAuthority not working](https://forum.aspose.com/t/aspose-pdf-java-pdffilesignature-setauthority-not-working/219738)" and a solution has also been provided there.